# How to Disable SignIn/Missing UserManagement Property in ASP.NET MVC 5 EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a project using Asp.NET MVC 5, but now I'm having some problems since its last update.

Basically, the application user, which inherits from IdentityUser, had an "Management" property, that through it one could block the user, i.e. disable the signin for that user.

1. How can I do that with the new Entity Framework definitions?
2. What is the SecurityStamp property of the User?

(Also, in [this ASP.NET Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) there is [an image](http://i1.asp.net/media/4391567/std.png?cdn_id=2013-10-18-001) that shows the project's database, and we can see a "AspNetUserManagement" table that isn't created, but maybe it's just a mistake)

**OLD Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.User:**

```
//...
public string Id { set; get; }
public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<UserLogin> Logins { set; get; }
public virtual Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserManagement Management { set; get; }
public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<UserRole> Roles { set; get; }
public string UserName { set; get; }
```

**OLD Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserManagement:**

```
//...
public bool DisableSignIn { set; get; }
public System.DateTime LastSignInTimeUtc { set; get; }
public virtual Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.User User { set; get; }
public string UserId { set; get; }
```

**NEW Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.User:**

```
//...
public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<IdentityUserClaim> Claims { get; }
public virtual string Id { set; get; }
public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<IdentityUserLogin> Logins { get; }
public virtual string PasswordHash { set; get; }
public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<IdentityUserRole> Roles { get; }
public virtual string SecurityStamp { set; get; }
public virtual string UserName { set; get; }
```